# AngularJS Uncaught Error: No module: myApp

Tags: angularjs

### AngularJS: Using angular.module & VM

I have defined my angular module as below and want to use VM as per guidelines. Not sure what I am doing wrong here but it gives me error in console:

> Uncaught Error: No module: myApp

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    Hello, {{vm.name}}!
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) { 
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = "John";
}]);
```

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dn7pkuf8/

Comment: As Micky said, when calling `angular.module` you need to have two arguments to create the module.  `angular.module('moduleName', [])` creates the module `moduleName`.  `angular.module('moduleName')` retrieves an instance of module `moduleName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of, you need to add an empty array(or an array with your dependencies) when you declare your module. Without the array, you will try to fetch the module with the name myApp instead.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Then you need to add the app name to the [NgApp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive in the view, else the angular app want bootstrap.

Try it like this

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
     Hello, {{vm.name}}!
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought instead of specifying at each div/page. We could manually boostrap as below: var app = angular.module('myApp');

Comment: @user1563677 you need to add the NgApp directive to make it work. Add it at a root element and not in each view. Check my update

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new module you must pass an array as the second parameter.

`var app = angular.module('myApp', []);`

Otherwise it will look for an existing app 'myApp' which doesn't exist.

Comment: No error now but it doesnt shows the output. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dn7pkuf8/7/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use ContollerAs syntax. I've set up the plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uw8eq47MiUsM3J5HAea7?p=info)

Your HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
      Hello, {{vm.name}}!
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Your Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function () { 
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = "John";
});
```

I couldn't get this working in your jsfiddle, but I think it was basically the syntax correction in the HTML where you use the controller, as well as the points raised by the others here (including ng-app, your javascript module syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct syntax to create the app instance.
The correct syntax is as below

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

So what is the meaning of the sysntax you wrote?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

It means you have already created the instance and you wish to use it. Now you will get why angularjs is throwing this error. Because instead of creating a new instance it will look for that instance which is not created.

> Note: The additional parameter [] is required to specify the
>   dependencies.  It means you can add the existing angularjs
>   applications. Means you can add the dependencies and use it.

And you complete js file should like this below

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) { 
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = "John";
}]);
```